# Is it possible to use the vscode: hyperlink to open a file or directory in Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, you're able to use the `vscode:` hyperlink to complete some actions (i.e. `vscode:extension/ericadamski.carbon-now-sh`). Is there a way to use that to open a directory?

For example, I have my `~/Projects/Handbook` directory, and I want to link to open/edit that on a Boostnote page using a hyperlink.

Comment: Are you writing an extension?

Comment: @MattBierner Nope. I just want it to open a certain directory on my local device 

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Open a project (or a directory)

```
vscode://file/{full path to project}/

vscode://file/c:/myProject/
```

Open a file

```
vscode://file/{full path to file}

vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json
```

Open a file to line and column

```
vscode://file/{full path to file}:line:column

vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json:5:10
```

More details: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/command-line.md#opening-vs-code-with-urls

Comment: are relative url's unsupported then?

Comment: VSCode then asks me if I want to open it, which is fine. once, but a little annoying every time. Is there a "allow always" option? or a "trust this source" option?

Comment: To open remote URLs, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4779. You need to use `vscode://vscode-remote/wsl+CONTAINER_NAME/path/to/file`